# Recharts tooltip data within chart legend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm using the React Recharts package and I'm trying to show the tooltip data within the legend rather than a tooltip that hovers around the mouse cursor.

I've setup some custom Tolltip content with a handler to pass the tooltip payload back to the Legend component.  I'd like to legend to update with the tooltip data as the mouse is hovering over the chart data points.

I have setup a custom tooltip react element for the tooltip content like the following:

`<Tooltip isAnimationActive={false} content={<CustomTooltip handler={this.handler} />} />`

The handler function is setup as follows:

```
handler(payload) {

var payload = [
  payload[0]["value"],
  payload[1]["value"],
  payload[2]["value"]
];

this.props.tooltipPayload = payload;
//this.setState(this.state);
},
```

The tooltip will display the tooltip cursor within the chart when you hover over the chart data points when the `//this.setState(this.state);` is commented out. However it doesn't update the react state in that situation as the chart isn't rendering again.

You can see the chart tooltip working but the legend doesn't update at http://jsfiddle.net/elronalds/1zwxh3bm/5/

If forcing a state update with `this.setState(this.state);` within the handler then the legend will update but the tooltip cursor doesn't output as you hover, so you can't see what data points you are hovering over easily.

You can see the chart legend updating at http://jsfiddle.net/elronalds/1zwxh3bm/6/ but the tooltip cursor isn't shown when hovering the data points.

Is something wrong with my handler on the `CustomTooltip` or how I'm updating the React state?  I'm new to React so I'm not sure what is happening here.